# HTML tag is not accepted in nodejs

Tags: node.js

in this code html table tag not accepted.i don't why within codes i have tried but result not came i want the table format with border style.html within code also tried

this is my html table :

```
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'aaaaaaaaa',
    to: 'bbbbbbbbbb',
    subject: 'Test',
    html:`<html><head> 
<body>
<table>
<tr>

    <th>Id </th><th>Templatename</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>TemplateContent</th>
    <th>Active</th>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>streamingTemplate.id.toString()</td>//here the table data should be a database not the defined one.
    <td>streamingTemplate.template_name.toString()</td>
    <td>streamingTemplate.description.toString()</td>
    <td>streamingTemplate.template_content.toString()</td>
    <td>streamingTemplate.is_active.toString()</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</head></html>`
};
```

Comment: I presume your HTML is really a string and not raw HTML?

Comment: whether it should be declared in string

Answer (score 0):

Your `<table>` tag is inside a `<head>` tag.

Change your structure to this :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: now i changed the table structure and space also cleared but no result  the same error <html>
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    came for me

Comment: var result =<html> <head> </head><body> <table> <tr> <th>Id </th><th>Templatename</th><th>Description</th></tr>
   <tr><td>streamingTemplate.id.toString()</td><td>streamingTemplate.template_name.toString()</td>
        <td>streamingTemplate.description.toString()</td>
        <td>streamingTemplate.template_content.toString()</td>
        <td>streamingTemplate.is_active.toString()</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: It is not clear what you see or not now. Anyway, I suggest that you'll update the question on the top of the page with the updated information

Comment: is there any solution for this one

Answer (score 0):

You have a space character inside your `<table>` tag. It is `<table >` instead of `<table>`

Comment: Did you fix the typo?

Comment: there is no error but when i run this at the time app crashed

Comment: D:\web\not\temp\templateContr
oller.js:97
    <html>
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web\not\templa\templateRouter.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...